# Displaying only free time slots which haven't been booked for any date

Tags: c#, sql, join, rdbms

The following query displays all free time slots for a specific which haven't been booked:-

```
 SELECT DISTINCT tbl_available.timeslot
FROM            tbl_appointment RIGHT JOIN
                     tbl_available ON (tbl_appointment.employeeID = tbl_available.employeeID) AND (tbl_appointment.apptTime = tbl_available.timeslot)
WHERE        tbl_appointment.apptTime IS NULL
ORDER BY 1;
```

This is fine but I'm trying to get it so that it runs this query based on any date which is passed in as a parameter using c#. (I only need help with the SQL side of things)

Using the following tables:-

```
 Appointment:-      Availability:-
 apptTime           timeSlot
 apptDate           DoctorId
 patientID
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know how to pass a parameter to the query, or where to place it on the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AND apptDate = thepassedindate
```

Comment: I've added this in, but I keep getting the error" Error in WHERE clause near 'ORDER'.
Unable to parse query text."

Comment: Just took a little tweaking with parameters it works in access and Visual Studio even though visual studio spits out an error!